# How does relative velocity change when there is a translation of axes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, relative-motion

I was going through a textbook (Hibbeler, *Engineering Mechanics: Dynamics* 14th ed.) and the following passage stumped me. The chapter was on the relative motion of two particles using a translation of axes. I don't understand how the direction of $r_{B/A}$ stays constant between two moving objects or if I'm mis-interpreting what the passage is saying.

> An equation that relates the velocities of the particles is
>   determined by taking the time derivative of the above equation, i.e.
>
> $v_B = v_A + v_{B/A}$ (12–34)
>
> Here $v_B = dr_B/dt$ and $v_A = dr_A/dt$ refer to absolute velocities, since
>   they are observed from the fixed frame; whereas the relative velocity
>   $v_{B/A} = dr_{B/A}/dt$ is observed from the translating frame.
>
> **It is important to note that since the x', y', z' axes translate, the components of $r_{B/A}$ will not change direction and therefore the time derivative of these components will only have to account for the change in their
>   magnitudes.**
>
> Equation 12–34 therefore states that the velocity of B is
>   equal to the velocity of A plus (vectorially) the velocity of “B with
>   respect to A,” as measured by the translating observer fixed in the
>   x, y, z reference frame.

Answer (score 2):

What they fail to mention is that the direction does not change in time ${\rm d}t$. Essentially since there are no rotations the direction of the relative position isn't rotating also.

Over finite time scales the direction does change. For me they are taking a simple observation and making it more complex than it needs.

Comment: I think I am mis-understanding what they mean by "components of $r_{A/B}$ will not change direction". I initially thought they mean the unit vector of  $r_{A/B}$ has constant direction, which is probably a mis-interpretation. Do they mean that i, j, k (of the translating frame x',y',z'), won't change in direction relative to the fixed frame x,y,z? If so I'm missing the connection between that and your second point.